# How do I put several elements on the second row in a div

Tags: jquery, html, css, layout, jquery-plugins

I am trying to use css in order to position elements in a div. I cannot use anything else but classes/id since the div with it's content is generated from a 3rd party plug-in (datatables). Hence, I cannot add any tags myself.

My problem is that I cannot position several elements on the second row. Only one is positioned on the second row and and the next ones are positioned (next to each other..) on the third row.

I want all select elements on the second row and all the other element on the first one. I want all elements on the first row to be positioned to the right and the second row one select to the left, one in the middle and one to the right.

Here is the code: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2nPVZ/4/)

Why doesn't this work and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is this what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/2nPVZ/5/ if so I'll make an answer for you :)

Comment: Yes more or less. I want all elements on the first row to be positioned to the left and the second row on to the left, one in the middle and one to the right. Add an answer and you'll get the mark :)

Comment: Now I noticed you added some tags. As mentioned, I cannot do this since the div is entirely generated from the plug-in. I don't have control over div and cannot add and tags.

Comment: @Nicsoft so you want all elements on the same line? As in, select boxes on the right and all other elements to the left? under the same line? Or two rows?

Comment: No, two rows. I did update my answer, should be pretty clear I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for, quite confused on the layout:

**CSS**

```
.dataTables_length, .dataTables_length2, .dataTables_length3 {
    float:left;
}

.DTTT_container {
    float: left;
}

.ColVis {
    clear: right;
    text-align: left;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2nPVZ/12/).

Comment: Thanks, very close. What I want to understand more is how I can position the elements to the right, in the center or to the left? E.g., the two divs on the first row should both be to the left. On the second row, I want one select to the left, one centered in the middle and one to the right. I'm sorry that my question was a bit unclear.

Comment: @Nicsoft can you draw up a quick mockup? I'm still quite confused by the layout.

Comment: Better up (I hope). I updated your demo. I managed to move the elements as I wont removing your .top div section and putting the float as I want for each element. This is now as I want with one exception. On the second row, the select in the middle should be aligned to the center, now it's aligned to the left together with the other select. [http://jsfiddle.net/2nPVZ/13/](http://jsfiddle.net/2nPVZ/13/)

Comment: Ha, posted at the same time... That is correct. I do understand why I was very unclear contradicting myself. I mixed up left and right in this post... But this is exactly what I asked for in my question. Removing the clear and changing text-align to right in .ColVis and changing float to right in .DTT_container made it as I wanted it (not asked for...). [http://jsfiddle.net/2nPVZ/16/](http://jsfiddle.net/2nPVZ/16/)Thanks for the help! Now time to study how all those align-text, display, float, etc works together...

Comment: "text-align: center;" in .top{}, is that the only sound way to achieve centered content? There's nothing similar to float (e.g. float: center; (I know that's not possible)) one can use on the div to center?

Comment: @Nicsoft there is another method but it requires you set an specific width to the element you want to center. Once a width is given you can center it with `margin:0 auto`, that is the most <i>sensible</i> way, but there are other methods like positioning it absolutely (not recommended, as it is very very troublesome) or using pseudo-elements to create a faux-column (also not recommended, as IE does not support it very well).

Comment: @Nicsoft if you have other elements under your `.top` class being affected by your positioning simply overwrite that rule on each class affected and align them where you wish, for example add `text-align:right` on the elements you wish to align to the right directly on their class.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep those things in mind :) It all looks fine in my main-project now!

Answer (score 0):

Hi plz check this link http://jsfiddle.net/2nPVZ/6/ 
just add small css in your css

```
.top div
{
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: This put all but one select on the second row and all other elements on the first row. I want all select elements on the second row and all the rest on the first row. I will update my question to be more clear about this.

Comment: Adding clear:both; to .dataTables_length{} puts the elements on the correct row. Now I only need to know how to positioning the elements to the right, left middle.

Answer (score 0):

> Consider the [css position](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) - [2](http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/) and [box model](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp) rules to
>   adjust the webpage contents. Use containers width and then use
>   positioning relative or absolute specifying width of containers if
>   required for adjustment.

check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2nPVZ/7/).

Comment: THanks for the links, I will for sure check those out. Your example put each select element on separate rows. I want all select elements on the second row and the rest on the first row. Updating my answer to make this more clear.

Comment: you have not put any js code there.. what have you tried so far??

Comment: No, not using js for positioning. I hope I don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
display:block
```

instead of inline?